# create jqgriid with inline editing

Tags: jqgrid

Using version `4.4.1`

Looked at the example here [row editing](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Tried to duplicate the sample but am unable to get the inline row edit nor am I able to add a checkbox to a column.

I want the user to be able to click a row, click edit button and the row becomes editable.

I tried following code snippet as well
...

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  var lastsel2
  jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid({        
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames:['ID Number','Name', 'Stock', 'Ship via','Notes'],
    colModel:[
      {name:'id',index:'id', width:90, sorttype:"int", editable: true},
      {name:'name',index:'name', width:150,editable: true, editoptions:{size:"20",maxlength:"30"}},
      {name:'stock',index:'stock', width:60, editable: true, edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}},
      {name:'ship',index:'ship', width:90, editable: true, edittype:"select",formatter:'select', editoptions:{value:"FE:FedEx;IN:InTime;TN:TNT;AR:ARAMEX"}},                       
      {name:'note',index:'note', width:200, sortable:false,editable: true,edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"10"}}                      
              ],
    onSelectRow: function(id){
      if(id && id!==lastsel2){
        jQuery('#rowed5').restoreRow(lastsel2);
        jQuery('#rowed5').editRow(id,true);
          lastsel2=id;
      }
    },
    editurl: "server.php",
    caption: "Input Types"
  });
  var mydata2 = [
    {id:"12345",name:"Desktop Computer",note:"note",stock:"Yes",ship:"FE"},
    {id:"23456",name:"Laptop",note:"Long text ",stock:"Yes",ship:"IN"},
    {id:"34567",name:"LCD Monitor",note:"note3",stock:"Yes",ship:"TN"},
    {id:"45678",name:"Speakers",note:"note",stock:"No",ship:"AR"},
    {id:"56789",name:"Laser Printer",note:"note2",stock:"Yes",ship:"FE"},
    {id:"67890",name:"Play Station",note:"note3",stock:"No", ship:"FE"},
    {id:"76543",name:"Mobile Telephone",note:"note",stock:"Yes",ship:"AR"},
    {id:"87654",name:"Server",note:"note2",stock:"Yes",ship:"TN"},
    {id:"98765",name:"Matrix Printer",note:"note3",stock:"No", ship:"FE"}
    ];
  for(var i=0;i<mydata2.length;i++)
    jQuery("#rowed5").addRowData(mydata2[i].id,mydata2[i]);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="rowed5" class="scroll"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  var currentID,prevID
  jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid({        
    datatype: "local",
    height: 300,
    colNames:['ID Number','Name', 'Stock', 'Ship via','Notes'],
    colModel:[
      {name:'id',index:'id', width:90, sorttype:"int", editable: true},
      {name:'name',index:'name', width:150,editable: true, editoptions:{size:"20",maxlength:"30"}},
      {name:'stock',index:'stock', width:60, editable: true, edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}},
      {name:'ship',index:'ship', width:90, editable: true, edittype:"select",formatter:'select', editoptions:{value:"FE:FedEx;IN:InTime;TN:TNT;AR:ARAMEX"}},                       
      {name:'note',index:'note', width:200, sortable:false,editable: true,edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"10"}}                      
              ],
  onSelectRow: function(id){
      if(id && id!==prevID){

          currentID=id;
      }
    },
    editurl: "server.php",
    caption: "Input Types",
      pager: '#pager',
  })
  .navGrid("#pager", {edit:false, add:false, del:false,search:false })
  .navButtonAdd('#pager',{
   caption:"EDIT", 

   onClickButton: function(){ 

        if(currentID && currentID!==prevID){
        jQuery('#rowed5').editRow(prevID,false);
        jQuery('#rowed5').editRow(currentID,true);
        prevID = currentID;
        }

   }, 
   position:"last"
});

  var mydata2 = [
    {id:"12345",name:"Desktop Computer",note:"note",stock:"Yes",ship:"FE"},
    {id:"23456",name:"Laptop",note:"Long text ",stock:"Yes",ship:"IN"},
    {id:"34567",name:"LCD Monitor",note:"note3",stock:"Yes",ship:"TN"},
    {id:"45678",name:"Speakers",note:"note",stock:"No",ship:"AR"},
    {id:"56789",name:"Laser Printer",note:"note2",stock:"Yes",ship:"FE"},
    {id:"67890",name:"Play Station",note:"note3",stock:"No", ship:"FE"},
    {id:"76543",name:"Mobile Telephone",note:"note",stock:"Yes",ship:"AR"},
    {id:"87654",name:"Server",note:"note2",stock:"Yes",ship:"TN"},
    {id:"98765",name:"Matrix Printer",note:"note3",stock:"No", ship:"FE"}
    ];
  for(var i=0;i<mydata2.length;i++)
    jQuery("#rowed5").addRowData(mydata2[i].id,mydata2[i]);
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  The jqGrid documentation and samples are a little flaky.  Have you tried a later version of jqGrid?  We're using 4.6.0 and a proof inline edit we did months ago did work.  Eventually. :)

Comment: There is no error in the console., just that the row is not in edit state.

Comment: If I comment out the restorerow, I get multiple lines enabled for editing. I do not want to use restore row but only want 1 row editable. Updated code to show that edit button enables editing on row select